# iframe close after submit

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I have a link that called a pop up view named class="iframe".
I planned to setup a form inside those pop up, but my problem is i need to close those pop up after clicking submit then my original page, or my pop up background will refresh it self.
My script :

```js
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>template/popup/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //Examples of how to assign the Colorbox event to elements
        $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"50%", height:"78%"});

        //Example of preserving a JavaScript event for inline calls.
        $("#click").click(function(){ 
            $('#click').css({"background-color":"#f00", "color":"#fff", "cursor":"inherit"}).text("Open this window again and this message will still be here.");
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

```html
<a class='iframe' href="#">POP UP </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into PostMessages

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

You should be able to dispatch a message from your parent page. Your window should then be able to close itself once it receives the message..
(this will work cross domain too)

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.open` to open your popup, and save it to a variable.  This variable will point to that window object.  You can later call `.close` on this variable.

```
var url = 'http://yourwebsite.com/subpage-within-your-website.html';
popup_window = window.open(url);
popup_window.close();
```

Note: Due to Javascript's security restrictions on iframes,  this will only work if called on pages that belong to the same domain.  I also wrote a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fwghp0zu/) but it appears they have sandbox enabled which prevents iframe access.

[This page](http://www.javascript-coder.com/files/window-popup/javascript-window-close-example1.html) has a working example.  [Source code](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-close.phtml).

Comment: Dear Ayrit, Thanks dude, it already helped me a bit, nut when i close the window, how can be the current window automatically refresh ?